# Is there a relationship between the transition moment and position?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Suppose that there exists two states which are not eigenstates of the position operator in a superposition:

$$
\Psi(t) = a \phi_1(r, t) + b \phi_2(r, t) . 
$$

The expectation value of the position operator is then given as follows:

$$
\langle \hat{r} \rangle = | a |^2 \langle \phi_1 | \hat{r} | \phi_1 \rangle + | b |^2 \langle \phi_2 | \hat{r} | \phi_2 \rangle + a^* b \langle \phi_1 | \hat{r} | \phi_2 \rangle + b^* a \langle \phi_2 | \hat{r} | \phi_1 \rangle. 
$$

The meaning of this is transparent and, if these states have different energies, the expectation value of position will vary in time according to the above equation.

Integrals of this form are oftentimes seen in quantum mechanics, where one is calculating transition rates between two different states through the dipole interaction (proportional to the position operator). Specifically, the transition between two different states, $d_{nm}$, is the off-diagonal component of the position operator:

$$
d_{nm} \propto \langle \phi_n | \hat{r} | \phi_m \rangle . 
$$

Given the similar form in this and the position expectation value of the above equation, is there an interpretation of transition moments related to position?

The motivation for this question is there are transition moments which may change sign or vanish depending on the orbitals involved (e.g. Cooper minima). Is there a position-related interpretation for situations like this?

Answer (score 0):

> is there an interpretation of transition moments related to position?

AFAIK only in the trivial sense you point out - expected average position (or center of mass of electronic charge) for given psi function can be expressed using similar integrals for pairs of Hamiltonian eigenfunctions. But note $d_{mn}$'s (fixed numbers) are only part of the expression, they are not sufficient, since the time-dependent expansion coefficients are important too.

Also, average position is often not considered interesting in light-molecule interaction because the material system is considered to be not moving or moving negligibly from the assumed position. But this would change if effect of radiation on translatory motion of the system is studied, or if there are multiple such systems with non-trivial motion.

It is known that if there is to be a non-zero energy transfer in dipole interaction (linear in electric field) between light and a pair of stationary states $m,n$ of an atom/molecule, the corresponding non-zero dipole moment element $d_{mn}$ has to be non-zero (this depends on the Hamiltonian) and also the assumed atom/molecule psi function has to have overlap with both corresponding basis functions $\phi_m,\phi_n$. The expected center of charge for this psi function will then manifest partial oscillation at the corresponding frequency $\frac{E_n-E_m}{h}$.

> The motivation for this question is there are transition moments which may change sign or vanish depending on the orbitals involved (e.g. Cooper minima).

If transition moment element of an atom/molecule changes sign, something in the Hamiltonian has to change. What is it, can you give an example?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Cooper minima are a good example of what I'm discussing. For the transition moment coupling continuum state and a bound wavefunction of an atom, the radial overlap integral will change sign and pass through zero as the energy of the continuum state increases for orbitals with a radial node. 

If you look at the integrand of the radial integral for the transition moment, it is clear that the 'dominant' region of the integrand is moving inward as this occurs. I am wondering if some physical meaning might be gleaned from this.

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about this. Are you comparing transition dipole moment elements for two different basis function pairs while the Hamiltonian is constant, or is the Hamiltonian changing due to some variable parameter? Otherwise I don't see in what sense is the integral changing sign. For given Hamiltonian and pair of functions, the integral is constant.

Comment: it is a calculation of the transition moment for a given atomic orbital to continuum states of varying energy. As the continuum state energy increases, the overlap with the given orbital in the integrand passes through zero and changes sign. So, it's not for a given two basis functions, but one given basis function and the subset of continuum basis functions. The Hamiltonian can be considered time-independent for the purpose of the question.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!